# How to show the data entered in textarea using django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to create a debate website. I am unable to show the data typed in my text-area on the screen. I create a model named **NoteModel** and in forms.py file I created a **NoteForm**. I am using views.py to save the data entered in the textarea.

App name: debate

html file name: content.html

this is my views.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def index(request):
     return render(request,'debate/content.html')

def NoteView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        m = NoteForm(data=request.POST)
        if m.is_valid():
            method = m.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('method/')
        else:
            return render(request,'debate/content.html', {'NoteForm': method})
```

this is models.py file:

```
from django.db import models


class NoteModel(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

this is content.html file:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">for</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">against</button>
<form method="post" action="NoteView/">
     {%csrf_token%}
     {{form.title}}
     <script>
          function myFunction() {
          var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
          var t = document.createTextNode("enter your for point");
          var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
          y.setAttribute("type", "submit");
          document.body.appendChild(y);
          x.appendChild(t);
          document.body.appendChild(x);
          }
       </script>
     </form>
```

this is forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *
 class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
             model = NoteModel
             fields='__all__'
```

Comment: Can you paste your form as well, since you are calling that in the template too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put for example an h1 tag you can see the data entered in the textarea with the `onchange` method, by doing the following:

```
<body>
  ....
  <h1 id="text"></h1>
  <form>
   ....
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
            var t = document.createTextNode("enter your for point");
            var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
            y.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            document.body.appendChild(y);
            x.setAttribute("id", "textarea");
            x.setAttribute("onchange", "showFunction()");
            x.appendChild(t);
            document.body.appendChild(x)
       }
    </script>
  </form>
  <script>
        function showFunction() {
            let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = textarea;
        }
  </script>
```